# Не могу сбросить webhook в telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, бот

Не могу ничего сделать с webhook, на любую команду

```
curl https //api.telegram.org/bot***/setWebhook
```

Либо

```
curl --data "https //myurl" https //api.telegram.org/bot***/setWebhook
```

Отвечает одинаково:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}
```

При этом вызовы не поступают. После первой команды должен быть ответ типа `Webhook removed`, однако он аналогичный `"Webhook is already set"`.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: сертификат загружать требуется только для самоподписаных, в моем случае это не так.

Comment: вопрос решен

необходим было вызывать curl:

curl -F "https //myurl" https //api.telegram.org/bot***/setWebhook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вопрос решен необходимо

было вызывать curl:

```
curl -F "https //myurl" https //api.telegram.org/bot***/setWebhook
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш набор webhook не был успешным действительно, потому что не был загружен файл сертификата, а показаны API вам "Webhook was set", но это было не совсем так
Вы должны заботиться о загрузке файла сертификата на серверы и убедиться, что ваш файл сертификата загружен, Лучше,  проверить API для загрузки файла сертификата и пусть разработчик знает об этом, если нет, отправить неудачную набор webhook